# Scrollmagic scene triggers on load of page

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gsap, tween, scrollmagic

Im developing my project in GatsbyJS(React). Im using scrollmagic with gsap and want to trigger animation based on triggerHook. 
The problem is that the animation is always triggered on page load and its ignoring the trigger element and hooks. Indicators are set up right.
Do you know where can be a problem ?

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import React from "react"
import letterImg from "../../images/Acko.svg"
import "./textBlockPageComponent.scss"
import { Controller, Scene } from 'react-scrollmagic';
import { Tween } from "react-gsap"

class textBlockPageComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Controller>
      <Scene triggerHook={0.7} reverse={false} indicators={true} triggerElement="#blockOfText" duration={0}>
      <div id="blockOfText" class="textBlock">
        <Tween to={{ opacity: 1 , y: "-100px" }} duration={10}>
        <div id="textBlockCont" class="textBlock__cont">
          <img class="textBlock__img" src={letterImg}></img>
          <p class="textBlock__cont_text">{this.props.text}</p>
        </div>
        </Tween>
      </div>
      </Scene>
    </Controller>
    )
  }
}
export default textBlockPageComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <Controller>
  <Scene triggerHook={0} reverse indicators duration={100}>
    <Tween from={{ opacity: 0, y: '0px' }} to={{ opacity: 1, y: '-100px' }}>
      <div id="textBlockCont" className="textBlock__cont">
        <p style={{ paddingTop: '3rem' }}>
          Test
        </p>
      </div>
    </Tween>
  </Scene>
</Controller>
```

I think the div between `<Scene>` and `<Tween>` is causing the problem.